# Parameters for ArcGIS REST ".../MapServer?f=jsapi"?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

What parameters can be used with `.../MapServer?f=jsapi` to alter the results, like turning on or off a single layer?

**Background:**

When browsing an ArcGIS REST Services Directory one of the options at a *MapServer* level is to "view in ArcGIS JavaScript":

http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer
[image: screenshot]

This leads to a light-weight web map with minimal chrome, widgets, etc. and no reliance on a 3rd party server like ArcGIS Online to draw the results. It is really handy for having a quick look at the service, with a bonus of having a shareable URL that anyone can see.

http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Specialty/Soil_Survey_Map/MapServer?f=jsapi
[image: jsapi map screenshot]

The problem, from my present perspective, is that the view is limited to the default definition in the MapServer service definition. In this soil survey example there are 3 layers in the MapServer. What I'd like to be able to do is use the same minimal-chrome webmap to view just one of those layers, not the whole map.

[image: screenshot of desired layer listing]

This Soils Survey isn't the best example of my dilemma since the desired layer will draw at the appropriate zoom level. The circumstance which prompted this question is a map service that has layers turned off by default. I can use ArcGIS Online's [Use URL parameters to modify maps](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/use-url-parameters.htm) `&layers=show:2,4` to fix that, but that invokes overhead and complexity I'm trying to avoid (using multiple servers and services for mere data viewing).

Answer (score 0):

That is just a basic viewer page to allow you to see the service. It's not meant to be used as an "app" and as far as I know, the ability to pass parameters to that page is not supported.

Comment: Absence of a doc page and public discussion for it says you're right. However there's a world of difference between supported and possible. ;-) I hold hope for the latter...

Comment: Matt, no, it's not even "possible" - a quick View Source confirms that. Your solution for using ArcGIS Online URL parameters is probably the easiest solution :)